# Woocommerce: rewrite regular price (main price) on the product page

Tags: woocommerce

Please help me find solution how change regular price to my price on product page. I created few new fields for prices in other currences and whant update regular price on product page befor adding them to shoping cart.

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow!** Your question lacks some information. Have you tried anything yet? If you need help with something you don't know how to do, you need to make **research efforts** yourself first and, if you have any problems along the way, bring those to us and we'll try to help! Meanwhile, consider taking the site's [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and stay on topic about [what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:

```
update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_regular_price', $custom_price );
update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_price', $custom_price );
```